# Are multiple unions of DataFrames efficient?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My Python 3 program reads a CSV file, performs some treatments on it, and then turns the result in a DataFrame.
Because the CSV file can potentially have millions of lines long, I do the treatment by batches of 10,000 lines that reside in memory, and then turn the result in a DataFrame.

Because I want to form a single parquet file in Hadoop, I want to write a single big DataFrame (self.df) which is the concatenation of all the small dataframes, like so:

```
def parallel_process(self, batch, processor):
    transformed = Pool().map(processor.transform, batch)
    return self.spark.sparkContext.parallelize(transformed).toDF(self.schema)

def process_rows(self, reader, processor):
    line_num = 0
    batch = []
    for row in reader:
        line_num += 1
        # parallel process a batch of 10000 rows
        if line_num % 10000 == 0:
            df = processor.parallel_process(batch)
            if self.df is None:
                self.df = df
            else:
                self.df = self.df.union(df)
            batch.clear()
            print(line_num)
        else:
            batch.append(row)
    # last (incomplete) batch
    df = processor.parallel_process(batch)
    if self.df is None:
        self.df = df
    else:
        self.df = self.df.union(df)

    # write the dataframe
    self.df.write.mode('append').format('parquet').save('table.parquet')
```

My question is, given DataFrames are immutable, is it memory and computationally efficient to do this or should union be used sparingly ?
What if, instead of appending a constant size batch DF of 10,000 rows to the big growing DF, I was storing all the batch DataFrames in an array (for instance), and concatenate them all at the end, is this something possible ? What are the memory and CPU usage implications ?

Answer (score 1):

> Because the CSV file can potentially have millions of lines long, I do the treatment by batches of 10,000 lines that reside in memory, and then turn the result in a DataFrame.

This doesn't make any sense and won't work as you expected. In fact all data passed via `.parallelize` will be stored in Python interpreter memory and further duplicated on JVM.

> Because I want to form a single parquet file in Hadoop, I want to write a single big DataFrame (self.df) which is the concatenation of all the small dataframes,

In general it won't work like this either. Number of output files doesn't depend on number of `DataFrames` - it depends on the number of partitions. Unless you `coalesce(1)` / `repartition(1)` (what is hard to recommend in any real life scenario) you'll get multiple output files.

> is it memory and computationally efficient to do this or should union be used sparingly?

Local complexity is non-linear (used to be exponential, but implementation improved in the latest versions) in the number of merged `DataFrames` so it not efficient. Good news is it doesn't affect task execution time, only the driver code.

What you really should do, is read data with `csv` reader, write with `parquet` writer:

```
(spark
    .read.format("csv").load(inpath)
    ... # Apply whatever transformations you neeed
    .write.format("parquet").save(outpath))
```

(adjust with options applicable in your case).

Comment: But this doesn't do what I want it to do. In fact I'm writing a small ETL. Your code bypasses the Transform phase.